# What solvents can solve aromatic urethane resins?

Tags: solvents, color

Do you have any information about chemical resistance of hexa-functional aromatic urethane acrylate?

I want to know what solvents can solve aromatic urethane resins.

Comment: You are talking about EBECRYL 220, right? *Hexafunctional* means that this is going to form a rather dense network. Its likely not going to be soluble. But why dont you read the application notes from the manufacturer?  --> homework

Comment: @Karl thank you for your answer .I want to remove UV INKS from plastic.these inks have been formed from some resins such as aromatic urethane .I can remove some color that have no aromatic urethane but I dont have what should do to clean aromatic urethane .